# Access to Windows Security Log denied from Powershell

Tags: security, powershell, windows-server-2016

I have created a Powershell script that retrieves information from the Security section of the Windows Event Log:

```
Get-EventLog -Log "Security" -EntryType Warning,Error,FailureAudit -After (Get-Date).addDays(-1)
```

This works fine if I run the script when logged on to the server (as an administrator).

I run into a problem when I try to run this as a different user. In my case, the Powershell script is invoked from within Oracle's job scheduler. This scheduler runs under the account "NT SERVICE\OracleJobSchedulerXE".

At first run, this produced the following error:

```
 "Get-EventLog : Requested registry access is not allowed."
```

Based on a little research, I then tried the following:

- Added the "NT SERVICE\OracleJobSchedulerXE" user to the "Event Log Readers" group
- Used regedit to go to HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Security, right click and select "Permissions"

  - Added the group "Event Log Readers", edited permissions and checked the boxes for Query Value, Enumerate Subkeys, Notify, Read Control
- Added "NT SERVICE\OracleJobSchedulerXE" user to the "Manage auditing and security log" user assignments via Group Policy

However, I still get an error, although slightly different than the first error:

```
  "Get-EventLog : Cannot open log Security on machine .. Windows has not provided an error code."
```

What do I need to do to give the "NT SERVICE\OracleJobSchedulerXE" access to the security log?